# Setting the SDK for ios build

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I uploaded my first Nativescript app to the apple app store and got a message that my build used SDK 11 and was ok, but future releases will be required to use SDK 12. I have been unable to find where you set the SDK the compiler uses. I have used a combination of command line to build at times, but usually the Sidekick app. Can someone help me know how to get my project to use SDK 12?

Comment: If you have installed Xcode 10.x it should use SDK 12 by default.

Comment: I do, but for some reason the Store seemed to think I had built it using 11.

Comment: Apparently it is a known issue for Sidekick. https://github.com/NativeScript/sidekick-feedback/issues/323